# Application portablity between Windows versions

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-7

I have an Delphi 7 Application that uses Halcyon dbf component. It works well in Windows ME.
Unfortunately in Windows XP data aware controls which are bound to [Halcyon](http://www.griffinsolutions.com/products.php) xBase Engine do not behave correctly. In addition pack command almost hangs the application. I tried compiling in XP. But no joy. Does that mean that API calls work differently? May be Data types mean different things....

Thanks for all help

Comment: Compiling in different versions of Windows make no difference whatsoever. You are running the same compiler and so it emits the same executable file.

Comment: This question is far too vague. In what way do the controls behave incorrectly? Also, what did the component vendor say when you raised the issue with them?

Comment: Halycon is a component from [Griffin Solutions](http://www.griffinsolutions.com/index.php)

Comment: Okay, I edited the question to put the link in.  I had never heard of it before.

Comment: This sounds like a good question to ask (with more detail) at the Halcyon forums...  What version of Halcyon you have, might be relevant. http://www.griffinsolutions.com/forum.php?room=main

Answer (score 1):

A well written Delphi 7 application will work on any version of WIndows from 98 onwards. If you have managed to make an application that doesn't work on XP, then you should debug the problem on XP, not recompile and then give up. (no joy!? what? you're done already? Is that how you troubleshoot and debug?).

For posterity I should point out that if you change Delphi versions then of course, some things change.  For example, If you build your Delphi application in Delphi 2009 or later, it will work properly on Windows XP, but not on Windows 98 or ME any more.  But if you build your application using the same version of Delphi, why would you expect any changes in the application's bugs?

As David says; Rebuilding your application on a different computer, from the same code, and with the same compiler, produces the same binary. If you have a fundamental problem on Windows XP it is because you made a mistake in your code somewhere.

In general, windows 98/ME to 2000/XP  was an easy transition, but that was a decade ago. 
The only API I remember that was in Windows 98/ME that was not in XP, was the Windows 98 text-to-speech API which was removed and replaced with a different API in XP.

I believe your confusion is that windows contains something that affects Data Aware controls. It does not. Data Aware Controls are a purely Delphi thing, and they are not a part of Windows XP, they are 100% implemented inside Delphi. If you have some funny custom control that is badly written, perhaps it might not work.  We have no idea what your code contains, and you haven't even described the nature of the failure.

You need to provide more information, or this question should be closed as unanswerable, or too localized. (My app doesn't work! Help! No other info given.)